# Spring boot read properties into Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a `Map<String, Product>` from my .properties file in Spring boot 3.1. I have written my custom converter for this, but it seems that it is never executing. I haven't done custom conversions before and I am not sure if a converter is needed in this use case or if Spring boot is able to manage the conversion automagically (If I configure it correctly).

product-configurations.properties:

```
products.product[0].name=FirstProduct
products.product[0].productID=1234
products.product[0].availableOptions=Opt1
products.product[0].processing=Parallel
```

Product class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String processing;
    private String availableOptions;
    private Integer productID;
}
```

Configuration class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:product-configurations.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("products")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductProperties {

    private List<Product> product;
}
```

ProductConverter class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.cb.clientfacingapp.model.Product;

@Component

@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class ProductConverter implements Converter<List<Product>, Map<String, Product>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Product> convert(List<Product> source) {
        Product p = new Product();
        System.out.println("I am converting");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Can someone pls guide me on this?

Thanks in Advance.

### Update:

Sorry, I forgot to mention how the map should be organized.

`Map<String, Product>` where String is basically the `name` property of the product, and `Product` is the POJO class for that specific product, So each Product is mapped to its Name, basically.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, is this what you are looking for ? for (Product product : products) {
   hm.put(product.name,product);
  }

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you're trying to achieve can be done without conversion

```
root.products.productName1.name=FirstProduct
root.products.productName1.productID=1234
root.products.productName1.availableOptions=Opt1
root.products.productName1.processing=Parallel

root.products.productName2.name=SecondProduct
root.products.productName2.productID=5678
root.products.productName2.availableOptions=Opt2
root.products.productName2.processing=Parallel
```

Therefore `productName1`, `productName2` would be your map key names.

You can use it this way:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("root")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductProperties {

    private Map<String, Product> products;
}
```

Comment: could you please help me how on how the properties file would like like if it was Map<String, List<Product>>. I have been struggling to configure this

Comment: @AmitGupta Very simple. Just add the array index to a properties definition. Like: `root.products.productName1[0].name=
root.products.productName1[0].productID=
root.products.productName1[1].name=
root.products.productName1[1].productID=`

Answer (score 1):

You could do what @Daria [has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62590131/3346298), which is the simplier way to do it.

In case you're still wondering how to convert a list into a Map, it can be done using Streams:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.cb.clientfacingapp.model.Product;

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class ProductConverter implements Converter<List<Product>, Map<String, Product>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Product> convert(List<Product> source) {
        return source.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Product::getName,Function.identity));

    }
}
```

It would generate a map with the product name as key value, and the product object as content value.